# asio :how does server actively send information to client while listening to client at the same time?

Tags: c++, c++11, tcp, boost-asio

The server accept new connections :

```
void do_accept()
{
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            connection_count++;
            all_session.push_back(std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_), io_service_));
            all_session.back()->start();
        }

        do_accept();
    });
}
```

and the session->start works like below:

```
void start()
{
    std::cout << "connection from " << socket_.remote_endpoint().address() << std::endl;
    do_read_header();
}
```

the do_read_header tackle the messages then recursively call itself. When tackling the message, it would call write to send some information to client.
The write function is below:

```
void write(const chat_message& msg)
{
    write_msgs_ = msg;
    do_write(msg.length());
}
void do_write(std::uint32_t length)
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.data(), length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            do_read_header();
        }
    });
}
```

Then here is the question: how does the server actively send information to client outside the do_read_header() recursion? I need the server dispatch some work which is decided by future user input to all the clients.
The boost asio c++11 examples don't metion how to do it. And I can't find some relevant resources on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I got your question correctly and you also want to understand how asio works with async operations.

In brief, everything happens in `run` function of `io_service` object.
When you call `async_write` or `async_read` in some function, you register a callback (that will be called when some event happens) and then immediatly return to the function. Then when all callbacks are registered it returns in `run` and waits for events.

So I will try to explain your code in detail. Method `run` is a kind of infinite loop, where it checks if an event has happened. First you register a callback with `acceptor_.async_accept`, return to `run` and wait. When a client connects, the callback for accept event is called and you register a callback with `boost::asio::async_read` in `session->start` (I guessed this one, since you did not provide `do_read_header` source), register the callback in `do_accept` again, return to `run` and wait for new clients or data. When data is recived, you call `write` and register another callback with `boost::asio::async_write` and so on... And in the end still return to `run`.

Since `run` is a blocking function, if you need to process input from another source (server console for example) you can do one of the following:

1) Use `run_one` insted of `run`. Write your own loop where `run_one` is called and other actions are processed.

2) Call `run` in another thread (also all operations associated with `io_service` will be processed in this thread), while in main thread process other actions. And a small example for this:

```
// here we process all network (or other) operations associated with io_service
void run( boost::asio::io_service& io_service ) {
    while( true ) {
      try {
        io_service.run();
        break; // run() exited normally
      }
      catch( std::exception& e) {
        // Deal with exception as appropriate.
      }
    }
}

int main( ) {
    ...
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    ...
    // start io_service.run( ) in separate thread
    auto t = std::thread( &run, std::ref( io_service ) );
    ...
    while( true ) {
        std::string line;
        // read line from console
        std::getline( std::cin, line );
        // process input
        if( line == "stop" ) {
            io_service.stop( );
            break;
        } else {
            send_to_everyone( line );
        }
    }
}
```

`io_service` is thread safe, so you can safely use async operations like `boost::asio::async_write` in main thread (in `send_to_everyone` for example) to register other callbacks and write/read data from clients.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. In the boost asio c++11 chat-room example, the chat client do issue another thread to call the` io_service.run() ` while process the `cin` loop  in the `main` to get information to send. But for the server part it just recieves and responds, works like echo. So if I want the server actively send information to all clients outside the echo loop, should I issue a new thread for every new connection. In fact, I don't process the input directly in `main` . I set a deadline_timer which `async_wait` for 2min then call the `cin` . Does it make everything worse?

Comment: I have edited my answer with example. No, you don't need thread for every client, all messages from them will be processed in ``io_service.run( )`` and inputs from server will be processed somewhere in initial thread. You can use ``async_wait`` and timer if it works for your needs, but this way you could not proces input from server as soon as it happens (only 1 time in 2 mins).

Comment: Thanks ! I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: By the way, do you know why does the `async_write` in `do_write` function need both `this` and `shared_from_this()`?

Comment: It does not, you can remove ``self`` from lambda, it will work. My guess - it is there to be sure that ``chat_session`` object won't be corrupted (deleted) before there is any registered callback from it.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but the problem i come across with asio is beyond my capability. I'm writing a picture album crawler of one social site(I like to keep the interesting pictures). The site has an anti-crawler policy which blocks ip if the user page view frequence is too high. So I begin to write a distribute crawler with asio. The http request, html parse, file save, file transfer module have been finished , the only obstacle is the the communication between the clients and server. The server accept the clients within 2min windows. After the timeout, server dispatch jobs to client.

Comment: The client send a register request to server. If the 2 min has passed, the server send an admit permission back to client and client would waiting for the jobs , otherwise a rejection message and the client quit.  The server dispatch the jobs with a end_of job message.After the clients finished the jobs, they send all the file  and a end_of_file message to server, then quit. If the server gather all end_of_file message from registed clients , it quits as well. That's the whole communication model. But the reality is always beyong expectation. The register,end_of job, end_of file are lost.

Comment: The messages are lost and I don't know why. I tried to figure out the problem and failed. May you figure out what's wrong with my code. Here is the implementation, `https://github.com/huangfeidian/C-S_Chat` , just 300 lines of code  .  Thank you very much.

Comment: It's hard to find error, you need to debug your programs, add more output with information to see what happens on both client and server sides. For example print size and maybe body of message you're going to send and on the other side print what you have recived. At least you can try to detect more specific problem and ask more specific questions.

Comment: I do output every send and read information to `std::cout`.  What I get from the debug information is that some  specific messages( register_request, end_of_job, end_of_file) are lost while other  messages(job dispatch) are not. The message decode/encode  works as wish. And the endian is handled correctly(just use the sprintf). Besides i test this demo on local, so the endian is out of focus. I cant imagine such simple demo would fail without a clue.